# Simple Web scraping PHP Xpath DOM

Tags: php, dom, xpath, web-scraping

I´m trying to learn web scraping and using this example to get the links from a page. Is there some better way to do it, or for example what is the easiest way to get the h1?

```
$html = file_get_contents('page.html');

//parse the html into a DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

//grab all the links on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    echo "<br />Link: $url";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to preface your expath with `/html/body`, `//a` should work fine.

Also, I would use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) instead of a for loop, but that is mostly a stylistic choice.

Comment: use php's curl function with domdocument instead of file_get_contents for scraping it is easy and powerful